# Excel equation- translating date, then next cell parameter not translating

Tags: sql, excel, concatenation, equation

I have an Excel equation which I am trying to build in order to make my life easy. It's essentially to build a SQL proc for our local db. I've never learned Excel formally so apologies for this possibly silly question.

```
 =CONCATENATE("EXEC [dbo].[_C00_SimpleValueIntoField] 163455,"&
    TEXT(E2,"yyyy-mm-dd"),",C2,","62993")
```

I need it to grab the date in cell E2 in the format of yyyy-mm-dd and then encase it in apostrophes ('1234-56-78'), and then grab the value of C2 (which is just a string of numbers).

I also then need this to repeat for E3,C3, and then E4, and C4 and onward...

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You should show us the current output from this formula and why it is not what you expect.

Comment: EXEC [dbo].[_C00_SimpleValueIntoField] 163455, 2017-12-01,C2,62993

Comment: That is what it is currently outputting as ^

Comment: I'm expecting it to show as this:

Comment: EXEC [dbo].[_C00_SimpleValueIntoField] 163455, '2017-12-01',123456,62993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently have `C2` inside quotes.  Try this version:

```
=CONCATENATE("EXEC [dbo].[_C00_SimpleValueIntoField] 163455, '",
     TEXT(E2,"yyyy-mm-dd"), "',", C2, ",62993")
```

You may find it helpful to put space in between the terms in your call to `CONCATENATE`.

Comment: That is excellent! That's solved that bit- but how do I get that date value wrapped in apostrophes? 

Example:
'2017-12-01' rather than just 2018-12-01

Comment: @SavviePirate Since SQL Server date literals should rightfully be enclosed in single quotes anyway, you may just surround the call to `TEXT` with single quotes, q.v. my updated answer.

Comment: Derp. Right, thank you- that worked. One last thing- how do I get this to repeat for E3 and C3, then E4 and C4, then E5 and C5 and onward for every row I have in the spreadsheet?

Comment: You should be able to just copy this formula down the column, and the cell references (well, the rows at least) should automatically move as well.  Then, just copy the entire column and dump it into SQL Server.

Comment: Awesome! You're right- I've had problems with that function working properly before so I was thinking maybe I had to do something else. Thank you for all of your help, Tim!